# VisualForce field displays + signs for spaces when reading from the parameter from URL

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page where I populate some of the fields from parameters passed into the URL:
For example, a field called "Description", should pick a specific tag from the URL and display it.
My tag in my controller is built in this way:

```
dupRecString +='Name: '+ result.companyName +'\n'+'Master Id: '+ result.Masterid +'\n'+'Matching Salesforce Record: '+ stripexistrecord
+'\n'+'Street Address: '+ result.addressline +'\n'+'City: '+ result.city+'\n'+'State: '+ result.state+'\n'+'Zip: '+ result.zip+'\n'+'Phone: '+ result.phone+'\n'+'Email: '+ result.email
+'\n'+'\n';
```

Unfortunately, the field on my page is displaying all of the + signs where it should be just a space.

```
Name:+Ms.+test+test Master+Id:+111111 Matching+Salesforce+Record:+includeinfunnel=true,+masterid=222222,+salesforceaccountid=O-444444,+status=Active] Street+Address:+115+test+Pl+ City:+Montgomery State:+TX Zip:+1111-111 Phone:+(000)+000-0000 Email:+
```

How could I fix that? Earlier in the day, it was displayed as spaces and the more I was testing it converted to using + sign.

Comment: have you tried instead of "+" with %20 ?

Comment: Yes, my apex code that is building/concatenating the string "dupRecString" does not like that syntax.

Comment: We'd need to see your VF code to help you further. There's not enough to go on here.